# Get event for NIC/ethernet card link status on linux

Tags: c, linux

Is there any API(or special file) on Linux that provides an event on the change in link status of an ethernet card without polling ? i.e. when you plug in/out the cable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get link up/down events via netlink. You would create a `PF_NETLINK` socket, bind to the `RTMGRP_LINK` group, and wait for `RTM_NEWLINK`/`RTM_DELLINK` messages. Link up events have `IFF_RUNNING` and `IFF_LOWER_UP` set in `ifinfomsg.flags`, while link down events have both flags cleared (funnily enough, I'm getting `RTM_NEWLINK` messages for both type of events).

Comment: Based on some experiments ( plug in and plug out of USB-Ethernet adapter)  I don't see `RTM_DELLINK` being received for ethernet. Can you please throw some light on when that event occurs.

Comment: @Vivek: `RTM_DELLINK` happens when a link is administratively deleted, e.g: `brctl addbr br0; ip link set br0 down; brctl delbr br0`.

Comment: Thanks much for the reply. I am newbie to using `ioctls`,`netlink` etc. Can you please explain what does it mean when it is referred as "Administratively deleting a link". I am seeing it in many places but not grapsing the meaning of the same.

Comment: @Vivek: it means that the admin deleted the link, as in the example. As another example, you can add a vlan link with: `ip link add link eth0 name eth0.5 type vlan id 5`, and delete it with `ip link del dev eth0.5`.

Answer (score 4):

If the contents of this file `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` are 1, then the interface `eth0` has carrier.

Comment: Indeed, but that's seems to not be event based, I'd have to poll to learn about changes.